# VB Excel Before Print Routine with mutiple printing

Tags: excel, vba, printing

In Excel, I wrote this code to run a particular routine each time the Print Button is pressed. It changes the sheet color to white and changes it back after printing.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Application.EnableEvents = False

' change color to white
Range("A6:BD53").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

' AfterPrint_ change color back
 Range( _
        "G6:BD6,G8:AD8,AI8:BD8,AN11:AO11,Y11:Z11,F11:V11,K13:AK13,Q14:AK14,J15:T15,P38:P39"). _
        Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Range( _
        "AB15:AE15,AU14:AX14,AU15:AX15,AU16:AX16,AA17:AC17,N24:W24,E28:O32,R28:U28,X28:AB31,AV37:BD37,V40:AL40,P41:U42,V43:AL43,V45:AL45,AV43:BD44" _
        ).Select
    Range("AV43").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It works just fine if I print each sheet singularly, but doesn't if I try to print many sheets at once, i.e. if I select more sheets at one time and print them. In this case, the routine is run only for the first sheet being printed and not for the others. Anyone knows why and what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this use of a `For` loop to go through all the selected sheets:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
On Error GoTo Err
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    ' change color to white
    ws.Range("A6:BD53").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    ws.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    ' AfterPrint_ change color back
    With ws.Range("G6:BD6,G8:AD8,AI8:BD8,AN11:AO11,Y11:Z11,F11:V11,K13:AK13,Q14:AK14,J15:T15,P38:P39").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With ws.Range("AV43").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next ws

Err:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As you described in the comments you are experiencing some unusal printing behavior. You can use this less elegant version of the code above, this should circumvent your problem:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
On Error GoTo Err
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    ' change color to white
    ws.Range("A6:BD53").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Next ws

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    ' AfterPrint_ change color back
    With ws.Range("G6:BD6,G8:AD8,AI8:BD8,AN11:AO11,Y11:Z11,F11:V11,K13:AK13,Q14:AK14,J15:T15,P38:P39").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With ws.Range("AV43").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next ws

Err:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I will be on lunch break for now, I will be able to add some explanations to the code afterwards.

Comment: thanks. I tried adding a loop, declaring a variable "sh" as Worksheet and looping "For Each sh in ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets" <mycode> Next sh, but it doesn't change the color even in the firs sheet now. In the code, I changed Range to sh.Range.

Comment: first I didn't, but then I saw you changed it, and it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: and now it doesn't work even if I changed it back to the original one, so I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to know what exactly does not work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: It just printed the sheets with color, even if I was printing out just one. No error window was shown. Now I closed the file and opened it again - and it works again but just for one sheet. I didn't change the code at all.

Comment: Try stepping through the code with `F8` and see what happens throughout the code's execution. Makes it easy to debug.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot debug the BeforPrint subroutine because it's fired by the printing button only. But I start to understand better the problem. The routine works in the Active Sheet, which is just the first one, if I select many in a row.
Just printing them, doesn't make them "active".

Comment: Just insert a `Stop` at the beginning of your procedure and you will be able to step through with F8. You do not need to activate worksheets to access the ranges on them, even if your code is running inside a worksheet module. Also, my code doesn't even use the `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `stop`. When it comes to the print.out command, it prints all selected sheets at once. The command `Range("A6:BD53").Interior.ColorIndex = 0`is applied only to the very one sheet that is opened on the screen.

Comment: @Frannzz That is some unusual printing behavior. I added another solution to my answer, this should now hopefully work with your case.

Comment: I just tried exactly the same as you are suggesting.. it would make sense to me. It doesn't work though. If I try looping even the selected _and_ active sheet remains colorful.

Comment: and even the `Stop` doesn't work. As if the whole routine isn't fired at all.

Comment: There is some weird stuff going on in your workbook and I don't think I can troubleshoot that from a distance without a lot more information.

Comment: Yes, still thanks for your help and time @M.Schalk. I will do some further research and post the solution if I find it.